# Reading Fileheader of a BMP with fread()

Tags: c++, linux, file, bmp

I am working on Linux trying to load the header of a BMP. I've looked at the header and should be getting "BM" for the first two characters of the file. The code I've been using:

```
FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
if(!fp)
{
    std::cout << "Unable to open file : " << filename << std::endl;
    return NULL;
}

char* headerField = new char[2];
fread(headerField, 2, sizeof(char), fp);
std::cout << headerField << std::endl;

if(strcmp(headerField, "BM")){
    delete [] headerField;
    std::cout << "File is not a bitmap" << std::endl;
    fclose(fp);
    return NULL;
}
else{
    std::cout << "Well done!" << std::endl;
}
```

The output I'm getting is BM followed by a random extra character, "BM7", "BMF", "BM*"... As I understand it, fread() should read in (in this case) two characters worth of data, so where is this extra character coming from?

Comment: The contents of `headerfield` are not being explicitly null terminated.

Comment: You don't need to dynamically allocate the two characters. And why are you using old C I/O functions in C++?

Comment: There is nothing "wrong" with the "old" C stdio functions. Just use them and the rest of the language correctly. Many C++ programmers skipped iostreams completely and still use alternate IO libs.

Comment: @codenheim Maybe it's not wrong to use it (debatable IMO), but there is a mix of I/O styles. And there are `char*` strings, which are not part of the I/O and could be avoided. One could construct an argument, that it's pointless to go c++ if only c++ specific thing is `cout`. It would be as much valid for the given example.

Comment: If using raw buffers, stdio is probably most appropriate. His bug is not an IO issue. There are explicit support in iostreams to synch with stdio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are heavily mixing c and c++, I think this is half of the reason why you got into the bug in the 1st place.

Now, in `c` strings are called null-terminated strings of characters for a reason. The null character `\0` is an end of string delimiter. What you are doing is reading two bytes into the `headerField`. So in memory it looks like:

> | B | M | garbage | garbage | garbage |

`str` family, and other routines expect the `char*` strings to have `\0` at the end. So the `strcmp`, and printing does not stop after `M` but run into the wild. A proper 2 character c-style string should occupy 3 bytes and look like:

> | B | M | 0 | garbage | garbage |

How you make it happen I leave up to you.

I would rewrite the code into a proper c++ personally.

Comment: Well, there is a problem, and explanation to it, and an answer is an answer, regardless of my own preferences. I'm not the one doing code-review =).

Comment: Thanks, re-wrote with streams and all seems well, using ifstream::get in pretty much the same way, which automatically appends a null terminator. 

I was following a tutorial with the code above, and they had no issue at all with using this method. Just out of curiosity does anybody know why this might be? The only difference I could find between us was that he was using mac and I am on Linux, could that affect the outcome?

Comment: @JamesHodgson If one gets (un)lucky `| garbage | garbage | garbage |` might as well be `|0|0|0|`. So it could work as expected. There is no guarantee what you get from system in the memory space you didn't allocate. At least not from standard point of view. Some systems zero all memory, so you cannot maliciously read it after previous process.

Answer (score 1):

The "extra garbage" is already there in memory.

fread() does exactly what you tell it. It reads 2 chars. C and C++ use null terminated char strings. cout is going to print whatever is in the buffer until it reaches a null terminator.

You should create a string longer than 2, and you should set a null char.